# Possible loop invariant

Tags: loops, invariants, loop-invariant

Consider the following loop:

```
y=1;
x=a;

//with a>=0 , b>=0

while(x>0){
  y=y*b;
  x=x-1;  
}
```

I wanna conclude y = b<sup>a</sup>

I been pondering for a while and cant seem to figure out a strong enough loop
invariant that allows me to conclude that. Does anyone have any idea how to approach this ?

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invariant here is y = b<sup>a-x</sup>.

You start off with x=a, so x-a is zero, and b<sup>0</sup> = 1, which is the initial value of y.

As the loop progresses, y gets multiplied by b each time x decreases.

At the end of the loop x is zero, so y = b<sup>a</sup>.